# Prevent GitHub for Windows from adding emoticons to my initial commit message

Tags: github, github-for-windows, emoticons

I'm new to git, and to GitHub. I'm using the GitHub for Windows program on Windows 7 64-bit. What I dislike is that when I create a new local repository, the initial change where the `.gitattributes` file is added is given a commit message containing an emoticon (seemingly chosen at random).

Here is a screencap of this problem in action: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXVkv.gif
The emoticon in the above example was "confetti ball": https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePYdv.png

How do I prevent this emoticon? Or at least, how do I prevent the inital change from being automatically committed so that I have the opportunity to *edit* the commit message to remove the emoticon?

Even though I'd prefer to interact with the program's GUI, I have enough practice with the command line that if the fix for this issue requires using it, I'm comfortable with that.

Any help for this would be much appreciated.

Comment: `git commit --amend`, then edit the commit message, then `git push --force` (if the initial commit was also pushed behind your back). I would stay away from github for windows. The command line is way better, and if you want a GUI, tortoisegit and sourcetree are much much better alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - that does work to edit the message, and I'll look into those alternatives. You can post your comment as an answer if you want, though I'll still wait a bit for any answers on how to change the default behavior of the program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
git commit --amend
```

, then edit the commit message, then

```
git push origin master --force
```

(if the initial commit was also pushed behind your back)