# How to remove emojis from my Github commits?

Tags: git, github, emoji, emoticons

I can find plenty of information about *adding* them. However, *I do not want them in the first place*. It seems like Github is adding these to my commits at random as I am most certainly *not* putting them in myself. I do not want "boom" or "camel" icons in front my commits...

Is there a way to completely disable this "feature" as well as remove emojis from existing commits?

**EDIT:** [It would appear that at least one other person has run into this exact issue and I simply couldn't find it when I went digging.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27033983/prevent-github-for-windows-from-adding-emoticons-to-my-initial-commit-message)

Apparently, if one uses GitHub's repo browser app, you'll have no choice but to deal with commits having random emoji garbage added to them. Also, [there is no way now or planned for the future to disable this](http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/3941362-disable-emoji-entirely).

Comment: You probably can't disable it, but you're looking for commit messages that generally contain the pattern `:.*?:` in them. If you were to remove them, then you'd wind up rewriting the entire tree depending on how deep they are.  You willing to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the only way to deal with this is to never to use the GitHub repo browser and amend any commits where emojis have been added.